# search and update string in all files using perl

Tags: perl

Need to search and replace the string in multiple file of same extension using perl.

I am using this code, but it is not working as expected. Can anyone please help.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

use warnings;

use English;

use Tie::File;


my $string2 = 'li role="prep" class="active"'; #old string

my $string3 = 'li role="presentation"'; #new string


my $string6 = 'div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="documentation"'; #old string

my $string7 = 'div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="documentation"'; #new string

my $quoted_substring = quotemeta($string2);

my $quoted_substring2 = quotemeta($string6);


my $dir = 'C:\Users\vkpal\Desktop\New_Report';

foreach my $fp (glob("$dir/*.html")) {

chomp($fp);

  printf "%s\n", $fp;

  open my $fh, "<", $fp or die "can't read open '$fp': $OS_ERROR";

  while (<$fh>) {

    #printf "  %s", $_;

    s/$quoted_substring/$string3/g;

    s/$quoted_substring2/$string7/g;        

  }

  close $fh or die "can't read close '$fp': $OS_ERROR";

}
```

---

I am using above code but it is not replacing the string. Can anyone please me here.

Comment: You have `use Tie::File` which would be one way to accomplish this, but you are not actually using it anywhere (see [docs](https://perldoc.pl/Tie::File)). Your current code is just reading the file, and updating the strings in memory.

Comment: Thank you So much. I have use tie::file now and able to achieve the desired results. we can close this question.